# Image not displaying - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-3, ruby-on-rails-4.1

Ruby 2.0
Rails 4.1
Windows 8.1
Bootstrap 3

I have the following in one of my views:

```
<td><img class="media-object" src="C:/projects/images/agent/1/thumb_johndoe.jpg" alt="Image Not Found"></td>
```

I verified that the image is there, and it displays properly in the Windows explorer. However, when my Rails app is running, the only thing I see is:

```
Image Not Found
```

The log file does not seem to indicate that there are any errors, it simply says:

```
Processing by AgentsController#index as HTML
  [1m[35m (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `Agents`
  [1m[36mAgent Load (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  `agents`.* FROM `agents`  LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0[0m
  Rendered layouts/_show_edit_del_buttons.html.erb (1.0ms)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An absolute filesystem path in your HTML code is always wrong.

Put your image in the folder `app/assets/images` and change the view code to show the image to:

```
<%= image_tag "my_image.png" %>
```

**Update**

If your images folder is outside your Rails project, add the path in `config/application.rb`

```
config.assets.paths << 'path_to_images'
```

But remember that you have to copy these files to the production environment or they will not be precompiled and deployed.

Another option is to use a CDN for all your external assets.

Comment: This does not answer my question. The images must be in that particular folder.

Comment: @EastsideDeveloper I have updated my answer but you have to understand the difference between loading an image from the filesystem and loading it from a webserver.